# ASP.Net URLEncode - Ampersands Inside Query Strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, ampersand

i have a query string like below :
`Default.aspx?path=/Play & Game&AnotherQueryString=bla bla`

the below URLEncode :

```
 lastpath = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request["path"].ToString());
```

output is like this :

`%2fPlay+`

how can we handle ampersands inside query strings / those ampersands are not delimiters between query strings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode the path before puting it in the query, because Request["path"].ToString() will always stop at the next &

like that = Default.aspx?path=%2fPlay+%26+Game&AnotherQueryString=bla bla